# how to implement dos match pattern by php

Tags: php, dos

```
* represent anything
? represent a character
```

like dos filename

`*.test.com` will match `aaa.test.com` but not match `test.com`

a dos like regexp `*.test.com` is similar with regexp `/.*\.test\.com/` in php

is there a builtin function to test dos-like regexp  in php?

Comment: preg_match is a normal regexp fnmatch is correct

Comment: That's true, however you can use preg_match with simple str_replace to achieve same results. I was actually writing that when KingCrunch posted his answer. BTW: Don't forget to accept his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see in your case [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) and/or [`fnmatch()`](http://php.net/fnmatch) will do it.

```
$pattern = '*.test.com';
var_dump(fnmatch($pattern, 'aaa.test.com'));
var_dump(fnmatch($pattern, 'test.com'));
```

Note, that this are not regular expressions, because this is just a much more simple pattern matching. I don't see a reason, why you should use regex here, thus at least `fnmatch()` should do it more efficient.

Comment: Didn't know about `fnmatch()`!